# Ubuntu Architecture showing "arm64" with Intel CPU for WSL

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed WSL Ubuntu 20.04 on my PC with `wsl --install`. Then I read the System Architecture info in the Microsoft Store for Ubuntu, and it says "arm64".  However, the CPU is Intel 12900K. Shouldn't it be "amd64"?

[image]

Comment: Nitpick: If it’s on Windows, it would be ‘x64’, not ‘amd64’.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It says:

```
Architecture: arm64 x64
```

Meaning it will run on *either* ARM or [x64](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/x64) (Intel/AMD).  That's not to say it's platform independent.  Technically, of course, it's a different package that gets installed for each architecture depending on your system.

In your case, of course, it's running x64 (a.k.a. x86_64).  You can confirm this from within Ubuntu by running `uname -a`:

```
Linux Revel 5.10.60.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Aug 25 23:20:18 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```